# Comparing Table Level Triggers against two databases

Tags: sql-server, redgate

I am using Redgate SQL Compare V10.7.0.18 to compare two databases, it works really well, however I cannot find an option to include Table Level triggers.  As my destination database has less triggers than my source database, so I would like them to be dropped, when compared against the source.

However cannot find a way of doing this without doing it manually?
Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't that show up as a difference between two tables? (Like indexes, triggers are attached to tables, not independent objects for comparison.) Perhaps you have set the option "Ignore DML triggers"?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ignore DML Triggers is currently unticked,  I have found the table level triggers actually appear under the object type of table.  When enabling these, and unticking include dependencies you click drop triggers that exist only on your desintation database